# Pentaho multiple type conversion from CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have tried pentaho for loading csv file and storing into Database. One of the column in CSV have multiple type values say 2.7777777777777E-06, 0, 2222, 2 , 35.023

My transformation doesn't support type conversion. Please help me for getting this fixed with right pattern for all type of numbers.

Error Message:

> Modified Java Script Value.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleValueException: 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Javascript error: 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Unexpected error
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - **Modified Java Script Value.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [Average String] to a Number**
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - **Modified Java Script Value.0 - Average String : couldn't convert String to number** 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - **Modified Java Script Value.0 - Average String : couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at position 18 for value [2.777777777777775e-06]**
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.scriptvalues_mod.ScriptValuesMod.addValues(ScriptValuesMod.java:475)
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.scriptvalues_mod.ScriptValuesMod.processRow(ScriptValuesMod.java:541)
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleValueException: 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Unexpected error
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [Average String] to a Number
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - 
>   2017/11/24 10:17:01 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Average String : couldn't convert String to number

Comment: These number can all get the type Number in the CSV reader. Your error comes form a Date, read with the type String, that does not want to be converted in a Number by a Modified Javascript Step.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. can you please explain this error "Modified Java Script Value.0 - Average String : couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at position 18 for value [2.777777777777775e-06] "  Actually i need to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `Average String` is read as a String not as Number by the `CSV reader`, and the PDI does not want it as a Number because it contains "e". Greetings goes to Javascript, not to PDI.

**Solution 1:** The best is to read is as a `Number`: [image]

**Solution 2:** If for some reason you cannot, you can use the `Select values` step to change its type in the `Metadata` tab.

**Solution 3:** If you cannot cast the String in a Number before to be in the `Javascript` step, you have to use an  explicit javascript casting: `var x = Number(x);` However, your variable name contains a space, and cannot be mapped automatically in a javascript variable. The [hack](https://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-136713.html) is do:

```
this["Average String"] = Number(this["Average String"]);
```

Then, you can get the `Average String` in the field list of the bottom table as a Number.